# How to constrain sceneview in specific extent? ArcGIS JS API

Tags: javascript, gis, arcgis-js-api

I'm newbie at ArcGIS JS API. I want to constrain SceneView with specific extent like [openlayers](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/extent-constrained.html). I tried extent property but the result was not what I wanted. Can you help me guys?

Comment: Did you try to use constraints instead?
[link](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-views-SceneView.html#constraints)

Comment: I tried but not worked

Answer (score 0):

`view.constraints` does not have the functionality you are looking for. You can probably implement it yourself by watching view.camera and constraining it when it goes out of bounds. It's probably a bit harder to do in 3D than in 2D.